# Returning multiple Parse classes in one PFQuery?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I currently have my parse classes set up as follows

1. User - objectid, usename, password, location
2. Profile - birthday, weight, height, et....
3. Settings - user app preferences such as "Show my location"

Both profile and settings have a pointer to the user objectid called "user"

Is there anyway I can call a query knowing the Users.objectid that returns both Profile and Settings?

I have played around with *includes key* and *matches query* but only get back empty results.

If it isn't possible is there a way to execute a function once both queries have completed? (using getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock)

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: whoops.  I just noticed the swift tag.  Is my JS answer intelligible to you?  I don't really shprechen sie swift, but I could restate in objective-c if it would be more helpful.

Comment: I come from a JS, PHP, MySQL background so yes. I haven't looked into parse cloud yet and this is a n iOS app I'm developing. Can I do the same thing with parse cloud for iOS?

Comment: Yes.  The cloud is nodejs and is common to all clients.  They supply a little command line tool to push code based on app id which is configured in a little json file.  Then, from any client, you'd use the sdk function to run a cloud function given the string name.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could hide the combination in a function....

```
function profileAndSettingsForUser(user) {
    var profiles;
    var profileQuery = new Parse.Query("Profile");
    profileQuery.equalTo("user", user);
    return profileQuery.find().then(function(result) {
        profiles = result;
        settingsQuery = new Parse.Query("Settings");
        settingsQuery.equalTo("user", user);
        return settingsQuery.find();
    }).then(function(settings) {
        return profiles.concat(settings);
    });
};
```

You could even locate that function in the cloud, so to hide the combination from the client.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("profileAndSettingsForUser", function(request, response) {
    // we could pass a userId in params, then start by querying for that user
    // or, if we know its always the current user who's calling for his own profile and settings...
    var user = request.user;

    profileAndSettingsForUser(user).then(function(profileAndSettings) {
        response.success(profileAndSettings);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: @AceGreen - see edit.  didn't return the promise.  sorry